# Embeded WebKit on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, webkit

Is it possible (as in, allowed by Apple and maybe provided as an open-source static lib) to use WebKit on iOS? I have a special situation in which `UIWebView` doesn't offer me the control I need, so I would very much like to use WebKit. I know that UIWebView is based on it, but also shades it, so I can't actually call the methods I need.

Also, what other realistic options would I have for rendering HTML + CSS and execute Javascript?

Comment: Well what kinds of things are you looking to do with webkit that UIWebView can't do?